# MS NLB - Dont I need a third server for actual cluster configuration?

Tags: windows-nlb

I think I am missing something here.
I am use to have at least 3 machines for load balancing.

1. cluster (proxy).
2. app number 1
3. app number 2 (perfect duplication of app number 1).

But, as I understand MS NLB, you only install nlb server on the actual web applications servers, meaning there is no third server that manage your connections and take decisions.
if you have 2 web app, you install NLB on them and thats it?

if it is correct, can you please share with me how can that be happening?
How can 2 servers take over one IP address?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you should [read the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756878(v=ws.10).aspx).

It is very thorough and should answer any questions that you have about how NLB functions.

From that article:

> Network Load Balancing runs as a network driver logically beneath higher-level application protocols, such as HTTP and FTP. On each cluster host, the driver acts as a filter between the network adapter’s driver and the TCP/IP stack, allowing a portion of the incoming network traffic to be received by the host. This is how incoming client requests are partitioned and load-balanced among the cluster hosts. To maximize throughput and availability, Network Load Balancing uses a fully distributed software architecture, and an identical copy of the Network Load Balancing driver that runs in parallel on each cluster host. The figure below shows the implementation of Network Load Balancing as an intermediate driver in the Windows Server 2003 network stack.

Don't be afraid to read TechNet. It's good.